# Duplicate Data rows in LazyDataModel primefaces

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, lazy-loading

I have a problem with The lazyDataModel in Primefaces.
If i have 1 result to show, one row is shown with the good one.
If i have 2 result to show, two row are shown but the two row are the same.
If i have 3 result to show, three row are shown but the three are the same.
...

Have you an idea ?
Why it doesn't work?

Before i try to do something not generic, returning the categoryId in the getRowKey but it was the same error.

(I dont know if it's tied(linked) but when i use the filter all the line disapear,no result possible)

Here is my datatable :

```
    <h:form>
         <p:dataTable id="table1" var="category" rowKey="#{category.categoryId}" value="#{listCategoryBean.lazyModel}" paginator="true" rows="7" paginatorPosition="bottom" 
             paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink}{CurrentPageReport} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"  
             rowsPerPageTemplate="7,20,50,100" widgetVar="dataTable" currentPageReportTemplate="(Number of Records: {totalRecords})"
             emptyMessage="No screenshot data found with given criteria" lazy="true" scrollable="true" 
             scrollHeight="217" style="width: 100%;">  


    <f:facet name="header">  
          #{msgs.categoryList}
    </f:facet>  

    <p:column headerText="#{msgs.common_name}" filterBy="#{msgs.common_name}" filterMatchMode="contains" style="width:25%"> 
     <h:outputText value="#{category.name}" />
    </p:column>  

    <p:column headerText="#{msgs.common_description}" style="width:25%">  
         <h:outputText value="#{category.description}" />
    </p:column>  

</p:dataTable>  
    </h:form>
```

Here is my bean

```
   private LazyDataModelBase<Category> model =
            new LazyDataModelBase<Category>(categoryFacade);

    public void setModel(LazyDataModelBase<Category> model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public LazyDataModelBase<Category> getModel() {
        model.setFacade(categoryFacade);
        return model;
    }
```

Here is The LazyDataModelBase :

public class LazyDataModelBase extends LazyDataModel {

```
private volatile AbstractFacade<T> facade;

private List<T> data;  

private int rowCount;

@Override
public int getRowCount() {
    return rowCount;
}

public void setRowCount(int rowCount) {
    this.rowCount = rowCount;
}

public LazyDataModelBase(AbstractFacade<T> facade) {
    super();
    this.facade = facade;
}

public final AbstractFacade<T> getFacade() {
    return facade;
}

public final void setFacade(AbstractFacade<T> facade) {
    this.facade = facade;
}

@Override
public List<T> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField,
        SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String,String> filters) {
    this.setRowCount(facade.count(filters));
    List<T> list = facade.load(first, pageSize,
        sortField, sortOrder, filters);
    data = list;
    if (list == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("La liste est null");
    }
    return list;
}


@Override
public T getRowData() {
      if(data == null)
          return null;
      int index =  super.getRowIndex() % super.getPageSize();
      if(index > data.size()){
          return null;
      }
      return data.get(index);
}



@Override  
public Object getRowKey(T object) {
    return object.toString();  
} 



@Override
public void setRowIndex(int rowIndex) {
    /*
     * The following is in ancestor (LazyDataModel):
     * this.rowIndex = rowIndex == -1 ? rowIndex : (rowIndex % pageSize);
     */
    if (rowIndex == -1 || getPageSize() == 0) {
        super.setRowIndex(-1);
    }
    else
        super.setRowIndex(rowIndex % getPageSize());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I corrected the error.
The error was i created a bean category in last jsf page so i kept information in requestScope, so the #{category.name} refer always to the bean created